# php loop with letters without using an array of letters

Tags: php, for-loop, phpexcel

I have an php code that writes an excel file with a variable number of columns. Each 4 rows, on the 5th I want to put the total of the four rows above, per column.

My issue is on how to write the formula in terms of columns.
My code is this one:

```
$col_index=20;
$i=20;
for($anno = $annoMin; $anno<=$annoMax; $anno++){
    for($mese = 1; $mese <= 12; $mese++){
        $string = "=$i$v+$i$q-$i$z-$i$t";
        $ews->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col_index,$k,$string);
    $col_index=$col_index+1;
    $i=$i+1;
    }
}
```

In `$string` I need to put the column letter instead of `$i`. `$v,$q,$z and $t` are the reference to the rows and are ok. In other words `$string` should be evaluated to:

```
$string = "=U5+U3-U2-U4";
```

during the first for loop,

```
$string = "=V5+V3-V2-V4";
```

in the second and so on. 
I know I can build an array of columns letter and use that $i reference to get my goal but I'm sure there is a better approach. I am using php 5.5 btw

The other option is to write the formula with the R1C1 notation but I'm pretty sure I cannot have the standard and the R1C1 notation in an excel sheet at the same time

Comment: `ord('U') = 85` and `chr(85) = 'U'` So maybe increment something and use `chr()`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver can you elaborate a bit your concept? I'm not sure I got what you have in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increment a string variable. I think this is the most efficient way to do what you need (if I understood it right).

```
$ch = "a";
++$ch;
echo $ch; //prints "b"
```

Knowing this you can build a loop to update the value as you need.
This works very good for Excel because:

```
$ch = "z";
++$ch;
echo $ch; //prints aa
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just concentrating on the column letter as that seems to be what you're asking.  Use the ASCII code of the letter and increment it, then convert it to the character:

```
$col_index = 20;
$i = ord('U');  // 85

for($anno = $annoMin; $anno<=$annoMax; $anno++){
    for($mese = 1; $mese <= 12; $mese++){
        $c = chr($i);
        $string = "=$c$v+$c$q-$c$z-$c$t"; // $i will be U then V etc...
        $ews->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col_index,$k,$string);
        $col_index = $col_index+1;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

If you need to keep `$i` starting at 20 and incrementing then just add 65:

```
$col_index = 20;
$i = 20;

for($anno = $annoMin; $anno<=$annoMax; $anno++){
    for($mese = 1; $mese <= 12; $mese++){
        $c = chr($i + 65);
        $string = "=$c$v+$c$q-$c$z-$c$t"; // $i will be U then V etc...
        $ews->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col_index,$k,$string);
        $col_index = $col_index+1;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Clever trick. Guess it will also work with AA, AB and so on... will test it!

Comment: Hadn't thought about the double letters. You would need to check if `$i>90` and do something else.

Comment: Yep! tested and it is so. Better to go with the array and use $i as array index to get the letter. Something like `$letters['$i']`